# javascript date, get past 12 months

Tags: javascript, date

I want to get the past 12 month for a running 12 month chart.

This is what I'm doing

```
function formatDate(date) {

    date = new Date(date);
    var day = date.getDate();
    var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    return day + ' ' + monthIndex + ' ' + year;
}

let now = new Date();

for ( let i=12; i>0; i--) {
    let newdate = now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - i);
    console.log(formatDate(newdate ));
}
```

And this is what I am getting: (Not at all what I am expecting.)

```
19 1 2018
19 2 2017
19 4 2016
19 7 2015
19 11 2014
19 4 2014
19 10 2013
19 5 2013
19 1 2013
19 10 2012
19 8 2012
19 7 2012
```

What I want

```
19 2 2018
19 3 2018
19 4 2018
19 5 2018
19 6 2018
19 7 2018
19 8 2018
19 9 2018
19 10 2018
19 11 2018
19 0 2019
19 1 2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to subtract 1 month only so don't use `i` coz it is dynamic value . The first loop is no need to subtract so do as below

Updated : you need to move current date declaration in loop , coz setMonth will change your date value so need to call current date everytime you loop...

```js
function formatDate(date) {

    date = new Date(date);
    var day = date.getDate();
    var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    return day + ' ' + monthIndex + ' ' + year;
}

for ( let i=11; i>=0; i--) {
    let now = new Date();
    let newdate = now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - i);
    console.log(formatDate(newdate ));
}
```

Comment: well - this just loops 12 time - and subtracts 1 each time - so it counts backwards, instead of counting from -12 forward...which is what I am after. Any suggetions there?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
let newdate = now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - i);
```

to

```
let newdate = now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - 1);
```

It's easy to see in your original code that month value is decreasing by 1, 2, 3, and so on. In every iteration you only need to subtract 1.

Answer (score 1):

`setMonth` modifies the date, it doesn't return a modified copy. So, the first time you call `setMonth`, you're moving the date back 12 months. The next time you're moving it back 11 months, for a total of 23 months. Then you move it back 10 months, for a total of 33.

Instead of continually moving the date back by `12 - i`, just move it back 1 month at a time:

```
now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - 1);
```

Comment: "*setMonth modifies the date, it doesn't return a modified copy…*" but it **does** return the modified time value. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
 now.getMonth() - i
```

to this

```
now.getMonth() - 1
```

```js
function formatDate(date) {

    date = new Date(date);
    var day = date.getDate();
    var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    return day + ' ' + monthIndex + ' ' + year;
}

let now = new Date();

for ( let i=12; i>0; i--) {
    let newdate = now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - 1);
    console.log(formatDate(newdate ));
}
```

Comment: well - this just loops 12 time - and subtracts 1 each time - so it counts backwards, instead of counting from -12 forward...which is what I am after. Any suggetions there?